# Getting ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string for a 2D complex numbers matrix

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I am trying to load a matrix of complex numbers but I get "ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string" in the console area.
I use the follow code to load and print it:

```py
test1=np.loadtxt('m1.csv', delimiter=',',dtype=complex)
print(test1)
```

and here is my CSV file:

```
-0.809-0.588i,0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,1,0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,1,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i
0.309+0.951i,1,0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,1,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i
0.309-0.951i,0.309-0.951i,0.309-0.951i,0.309-0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,1,1
-0.809+0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i,1,0.309+0.951i,1,0.309+0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i
1,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,0.309+0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,1,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,0.309+0.951i,0.309+0.951i,-0.809-0.588i
0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,1,-0.809-0.588i,1,-0.809-0.588i,0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i
0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,1,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,1,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i
-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,0.309+0.951i,0.309+0.951i,0.309+0.951i,0.309+0.951i,1,1
1,0.309+0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i,0.309-0.951i,1,0.309+0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809-0.588i,0.309-0.951i
-0.809-0.588i,1,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,0.309+0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309-0.951i,0.309+0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,1,0.309+0.951i,-0.809-0.588i
0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,1,-0.809-0.588i,0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i,1,-0.809-0.588i,0.309+0.951i,0.309-0.951i,-0.809+0.588i
-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,1,0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i,1,0.309-0.951i,-0.809-0.588i,-0.809+0.588i,0.309+0.951i
```

Comment: Try replacing `i` with `j`, because reasons.

Comment: it seems excel is having trouble with the negative numbers at the beginning of a sentence. Also numpy dosn't recognize it as an array of complex numbers.